Transform NCDU JSON output file to hierarchical json data like flare.json [d3 example file]
I want to convert the NCDU json file (https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/jsonfmt) to a hierarchical json that can be imported in D3.js using D3.json(). Here is the D3 sample file  flare.json (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/main/test/data/flare.json).
Tree structure where NCDU is run:
dotfiles/
├── apache
│   └── security.conf
├── bash
│   └── bin
│       ├── ipChangeAlert.sh
│       ├── mycommands.sh
│       └── send_reboot_email.sh
└── settingUpGit.md

NCDU output data.json:
[1,1,{"progname":"ncdu","progver":"1.15.1","timestamp":1717703526},
[{"name":"dotfiles","asize":4096,"ino":6192449488235659},
[{"name":"apache","asize":4096,"ino":1970324837438018},
{"name":"security.conf","asize":97,"ino":2251799814148886}],
[{"name":"bash","asize":4096,"ino":2251799814286493},
[{"name":"bin","asize":4096,"ino":1970324837438020},
{"name":"ipChangeAlert.sh","asize":1187,"dsize":4096,"ino":1970324837438249},
{"name":"mycommands.sh","asize":2421,"dsize":4096,"ino":2251799814148893},
{"name":"send_reboot_email.sh","asize":356,"ino":1970324837438244}]],
[{"name":"htop","asize":4096,"ino":1407374884154553}],
{"name":"settingUpGit.md","asize":2504,"dsize":4096,"ino":1970324837438080}
]]

Desired output:
{
  "name": "dotfiles",
  "asize": 4096,
  "dsize": 0,
  "ino": 6192449488235659,
  "hlnkc": false,
  "read_error": false,
  "nlink": 1,
  "notreg": false,
  "extension": "",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "apache",
      "asize": 4096,
      "dsize": 0,
      "ino": 1970324837438018,
      "hlnkc": false,
      "read_error": false,
      "nlink": 1,
      "notreg": false,
      "extension": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "security.conf",
          "asize": 97,
          "dsize": 0,
          "ino": 2251799814148886,
          "hlnkc": false,
          "read_error": false,
          "nlink": 1,
          "notreg": false,
          "extension": "conf"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have tried using both jq in bash and iterating through the list in python, but neither approach seems to be managing the structure correctly, and I am getting directories that are dropped or files that are considered directories


I have tried using both js in bash and iterating through the list in python

If you don't mind using jq, here's one way:
Ncdu encodes directories as arrays, and other files as objects. A file's information is stored in the object itself, a directory's information is stored in a similar object as first item of the array, while its children, being recursively encoded either as arrays or objects, make up the rest of the array (starting at position 1). To convert this into an object where children live under a dedicated children key, just take the first item of the array, and add that key filled with the rest of the array while recursively applying the conversion to each of its items.
jq 'def c: (arrays | .[0] + {children: [.[1:][] | c]}) // .; last | c' ncdu.json

{
  "name": "dotfiles",
  "asize": 4096,
  "ino": 6192449488235659,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "apache",
      "asize": 4096,
      "ino": 1970324837438018,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "security.conf",
          "asize": 97,
          "ino": 2251799814148886
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "bash",
      "asize": 4096,
      "ino": 2251799814286493,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "bin",
          "asize": 4096,
          "ino": 1970324837438020,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "ipChangeAlert.sh",
              "asize": 1187,
              "dsize": 4096,
              "ino": 1970324837438249
            },
            {
              "name": "mycommands.sh",
              "asize": 2421,
              "dsize": 4096,
              "ino": 2251799814148893
            },
            {
              "name": "send_reboot_email.sh",
              "asize": 356,
              "ino": 1970324837438244
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "htop",
      "asize": 4096,
      "ino": 1407374884154553,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "settingUpGit.md",
      "asize": 2504,
      "dsize": 4096,
      "ino": 1970324837438080
    }
  ]
}

Demo

wow thanks for this. Doing this in Python was definitely not the elegant way to go.
